# Conda broken after package uninstall

Tags: anaconda

I have created conda environments in the past without any problems. So, even this time I proceeded to create one.
 `conda create -n astropython anaconda`

Next, the documentation recommended uninstalling any previous copies of astropy by running: 
 `conda uninstall astropy`
I did that, and now my conda is broken. If I run any command with conda, I get the following error traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 19, in get_yaml
    import ruamel_yaml as yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel_yaml'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 22, in get_yaml
    import ruamel.yaml as yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1062, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 74, in _main
    from ..base.context import context
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, ConfigurationLoadError, MapParameter,
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .serialize import yaml_load
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 30, in <module>
    yaml = get_yaml()
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/decorators.py", line 59, in _memoized_func
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 24, in get_yaml
    raise ImportError("No yaml library available.\n"
ImportError: No yaml library available.
To proceed, conda install ruamel_yaml

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 19, in get_yaml
    import ruamel_yaml as yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel_yaml'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 22, in get_yaml
    import ruamel.yaml as yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 150, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1354, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1065, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1109, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1120, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1175, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .base.context import context
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, ConfigurationLoadError, MapParameter,
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .serialize import yaml_load
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 30, in <module>
    yaml = get_yaml()
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/decorators.py", line 59, in _memoized_func
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 24, in get_yaml
    raise ImportError("No yaml library available.\n"
ImportError: No yaml library available.
To proceed, conda install ruamel_yaml
```

Running `conda install ruamel_yaml` again spits out the same traceback. My $PATH is correct, solution to [No module named ruamel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733906/python-conda-traceback-no-module-named-ruamel-yaml-comments) did not solve the issue.

So, I looked into the files and found that there was no ruamel_yaml folder in the site-packages dir.  I copied the ruamel_yaml folder from `$HOME/anaconda3/pkgs/ruamel_yaml0.15.71/` to `$HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`. Now, when I run any conda commands, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1062, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
    module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .install import install
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import calculate_channel_urls, get_index
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_package_handling/api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from libarchive.exception import ArchiveError as _LibarchiveArchiveError
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libarchive/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .entry import ArchiveEntry
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libarchive/entry.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ctypes import c_char_p, create_string_buffer
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 150, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1354, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1065, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1109, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1120, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1190, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_package_handling/api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from libarchive.exception import ArchiveError as _LibarchiveArchiveError
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libarchive/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .entry import ArchiveEntry
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libarchive/entry.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ctypes import c_char_p, create_string_buffer
  File "/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/vsanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you figure out the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be a popular answer, but it finally helped me after many hours of troubleshooting:

1. Uninstall conda (I used [this stack overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos/42182997#42182997)) and also `rm -rf` miniconda3 in my home directory, fwiw.
2. Reinstalled conda using [data camp's tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/installing-anaconda-mac-os-x).

No other solutions worked for me after lots of head banging.